# Is it possible to download data from a lost iPod?

Tags: ipod-touch, find-my-iphone

My daughter's iPod has been (hmmm) taken ^^.

I can see it in the "Find my iPhone" app, but before I cancel or wipe it, **is it possible to download the content from there?**

The content is mainly pictures taken on the iPod (the rest of course is in the App Store).

Comment: Were iCloud backups enabled, and working? It seems if Find My iPhone was enabled that they would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't initiate a backup remotely, but you could log into iCloud on another device or a computer and look to see when the last iCloud backup of that device was completed to know what might be lost if you erase it.

Also look in iTunes under the preferences for devices to see if you have a local backup of the device as well.

On the iCloud preference pane for Mac, you can press the manage button next to the storage graph at the bottom of the window and inspect the date/time of the last backup for each device you have established.

[image]

Comment: OK, supposed I have logged in to iCloud with my desktop Mac.  Now ... how do I find out about iPhone backups that are there?

Comment: On the Mac, in System Preferences > iCloud > manage ... I can see a backup listed there.  But how could I access it without the iPhone?

Comment: You can't get to it other than know you can restore it on to a loaner device and then sync. It really depends what you have to restore and when you will replace the device. It should rest safely and you'll want to send a remote wipe to prevent someone else from deleting things and then over-writing this backup. Sadly - you have to choose to lose all tracking and protect the backup or keep tracking active and risk losing the data until you can borrow another device to restore the backup and re-save it under a new name.

Comment: There also may be the last 30 days worth of photos in Photostream. Enable that in iPhoto to check